# React-Redux mapStateToProps doesn't update component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I simplified my code but basically I have a straight-forward redux store:

```
/* store.js */

import { createStore } from 'redux';

const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'action') state.data = data;
  return state;
}

const store = createStore(reducer);

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(store.getState()); // returns the right state, updates properly
});

export default store;
```

A Loader that that pulls the data from the server and dispatches it to the store:

```
/* Loader.js */

class Loader {
  dispatch (allDocuments) {
    store.dispatch({
      type: 'action',
      data: data
    });
  }

  async fetchData () {
    try {
      const allDocuments = await ajaxCall('GET', '/fetchData');
      this.dispatch(allDocuments);
      return allDocuments;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
}

export default Loader;
```

And then this is my App.js file where I fire the Loader fetch method every 5 seconds and map the store state to a React component:

```
/* App.js */

import Loader from './Loader';
const loader = new Loader();

setInterval(async () => {
  await loader.fetchData();
}, 5000);

const App = ({
  data
}) => {
  console.log(data); //doesn't update

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{data}</p>
    </div>
  )
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({data: state.data,})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

So the problem here is that the component does not update. Loader dispatches properly, and the redux store does get updated but the data prop in App remains an empty object, and doesn't refire the render method.

Why is mapStateToProps not updating the component when the store state changes?

Comment: Is `App` wrapped in a redux store provider providing the same store that you are working with externally?

Comment: The more I look at this code, the more I hate it. Your `setInterval` is outside of the component and it never stops.  Your `Loader` accesses the `store` directly rather than using the react-redux bindings (`connect`/`useDispatch`).  I think this one's a typo, but what the heck is the `data` variable in `state.data = data`?!

Comment: I totally agree with Linda... just about all that this code is doing should be considered anti-pattern within the React component lifecycle construct. Is the redux store part of some larger app that isn't specific to React? In React you pretty much don't ever use the `store` object directly to dispatch actions.

Comment: For what are trying to do, which is to re-fetch data every 5 seconds and store it in Redux, I would recommend using the built-in "polling" feature of RTK Query: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/polling

Comment: Wait why is the Loader being outside a React component a bad thing?? Does it not make sense to have a non-react class update the data from the sever without any ui and then have the front-end elements use that?

Answer (score 1):

`mapStateToProps` expects that you will not mutate the state.  The problem is your reducer, which is mutating the `state` variable by assigning directly to `state.data`.

To avoid mutating the state, you'll want to return a new copy of the object whenever you change the `data`.  Like this:

```
const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'action') {
     return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload
     }
  return state;
}
```

Of course if you only have one type of action than redux is not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Your reducer doesn't save the `action.data` payload. It also isn't returning a new state object reference.

```
const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'action') state.data = data; // <-- mutation
  return state;
}
```

When the action type matches then you should return a new state object reference with the `action.data` payload.

```
const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'action') {
    return {
      ...state,
      data: action.data;
    };
  }

  return state;
}
```